# What is being done during python model instantiation

Tags: python, django

I am fairly new to Python and have been reading django tutorials. I came across the following:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


>>> p = Poll(question="What's new?", pub_date=timezone.now())
```

Question:
Is question an instance variable? Why is "`this.question = ...`" missing?
The poll object instantiation looks like assigning properties while intantiating a class in languages like C#. What is being done here? Not sure what terms to look up to refer the concepts used  here.

Comment: You should read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/

Answer (score 2):

It uses a metaclass.

When the class is declared, and fields are added, they register with the model class.

Then, when a new instance is created, it gets values for the fields, either passed in, or from the field default.

This is a bit of a simplification, but not that much.

You can read the `models.Model` class definition without having to understand how the metaclass stuff works though.